# What is the decimal expansion of the difference of two irrational numbers

Tags: real-analysis, decimal-expansion

What is the decimal expansion of the difference of two irrational numbers $x$ and $y$ in term of the decimal expansions of $x$ and $y$.

I know that irrational number is a number which contains non-terminating and non-repeating decimal expansion. This fact makes some difficulties when calculating the difference of the decimal expansions of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Ummm....  answer:   $x - y$.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork: Yes it is this difference.

Comment: Context? Your attempt? Very unambitious question.

Comment: It can be bounded $x = \pi + 10^{-1}, y = \pi$ or whatever: for example $\pi - e$ might be transcendental...

Comment: Do show what you have tried, e.g. are you asking "What is $\pi-\phi=3.14...-1.618...?"$ You could negate your downvotes if you edit your answer to let others understand the problem you are trying to answer.

Comment: This is actually a good question, and Chris Culter's answer explains why: you might find yourself having to compute a million digits of $x$ and $y$ to determine the seventh digit of $x-y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subtlety here is that each digit may depend on an unbounded number of other digits. For example, what is the first digit after the decimal point of this difference?

$$0.247747474747747474\ldots-0.147747474747747474\ldots$$

The digits provided aren't enough to tell if the difference is $0.1000\ldots$ or $0.0999\ldots$. It depends on which term turns out to be larger, and you may have to seek arbitrarily fair to find that out. So if you were hoping for a simple arithmetical expression for each digit, you're out of luck.